# Powershell - Setting folder permissions

Tags: powershell

Hi I want to give Domain Users full access to a folder with PowerShell. I am working with this set of code gleaned from research using Technet and blogs. I am still having issues.

I am getting this error when I run the code just below:

```
Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all     identity references could not be translated."
At line:13 char:1
+ $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException
```

Here is my code:

```
$directory = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app.webservice"
$domainName = (gwmi Win32_NTDomain).DomainName
$group = 'Domain Users'
$inherit = [system.security.accesscontrol.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
$propagation = [system.security.accesscontrol.PropagationFlags]"None"
$acl = (Get-Item $directory).GetAccessControl("Access")
$user = "{0}\{1}" -f "$domainName", $group
$user.trim()
$access = "FullControl"
$accessType = "Allow"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList @("$user","$access", "$inherit", "$propagation", "$accessType")
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
set-acl $directory $acl
```

I have tried replacing the $user variable with "domain\Domain Users" and the code works as expected. I have been unable to figure out how to pass the $user variable correctly so that the user parameter can be passed and not hard coded.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of your DomainName variable. If I run the same code here I get not only the domain I am running on but also all trusted domains as an array. This means the $user variable contains something like `MyDomain OtherDomain\Domain Users`.

I recommend declaring the domain as `$domainName = "MyDomain"` if possible. If you do need to dynamically get the domain you'll need to test for an array;

```
$domainName = (gwmi Win32_NTDomain).DomainName
if ($domainName -is [array]) { $domainName = $domainName[0] }
```

NOTE: My domain is alphabetically first so I don't know if the current domain is displayed first or if they are simply displayed alphabetically. You'll need to test and find a solution that works for you.

EDIT: Looks like `$domainName = $env:USERDOMAIN` might do the trick

Comment: I would definitely go for `$env:USERDOMAIN` (user) or `(gwmi Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain` (machine) instead of `Win32_NTDomain`

Comment: Thank you Deadly-Bagel. This code works for something I, too, need.